# Should I delete my own question if it turns out trivial after a comment?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, comments, deletions

I had not given [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216032/sign-patterns-in-kernel-and-rowspace-of-a-matrix) enough thought before asking it.  I went straight to looking for a reference without thinking about it.  Somebody pointed out the obvious solution in a comment.  Should I delete the question or give the commenter the chance to turn this into an answer (and earn reputation) ?

Comment: My own opinion is that it's fine to delete if you wish, before someone posts an answer. After someone posts an answer, it gets a lot stickier. I think you conveyed your appreciation well to the respondent; I think that's enough in this circumstance.

Comment: If you think that someone else might benefit from the answer, it does no harm to leave the question on the site. You can ask the commenter to turn the comment into an answer or, if necessary, provide a CW answer yourself. If you think the question is unlikely to be worth anything to others, you can delete it as Todd suggests.

Comment: I deleted the question on mathoverflow. It still lives in math.se where it is probably appropriate.

Comment: This is technically OT here but: in my mind it is more important you do something about the  [math.se] version: self-answer or delete, but please do not let the question just sit there unanswered.

Comment: Yes that was always the plan. I'm just busy with a toddler arm.

Comment: Toddler asleep, question updated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386382/sign-patterns-in-kernel-and-rowspace-of-a-matrix/1416164#1416164 Thanks for all your input.  Out of curiosity: Why don't you answer the question and we are having this discussion in the comments?

Comment: @Todd I prefer(at  least from now on) to not delete my question which  turns out trivial after a  comment. Because this would respect the  commenters help. But  I have  a  general question on the  philosophy and reason of  deletion:

Comment: What would be happen if  all question would  remain forever?So no longer we see "vote to  close" by 5 participant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the comment question, "Why not just answer the question instead of discussing in comments?", my belief is that your question is both too general and too specific for meta.  The specific question for meta was your question above, and (except for one snag), the specific meta question has served its purpose and could be deleted too.  The general question, how to decide, is a good question to which there is no good answer.  The community may decide a question should be closed if it does not meet certain criteria, but aside from not being spam or unfriendly, there are no rigid technical criteria.

In short, there is no good answer to the question.  It really depends on many factors, not just the content of the question.

Gerhard "This Answer Is A Snag" Paseman, 2015.08.31

Comment: - Lol such meta